# MySQL join tables and use two different records from joined table in two different columns of main table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create new table - `new_data` in which i'm going to store data about campaigns from two different tables 
. I have table - `campaign_revenue` with a column `data_date` to indicate...data date, and another column `revenue`.
in another table - `campaign_manager` i have the columns `revenue` and `revenue_yesterday` . so what i want is to join the two tables and take the `revenue` and `revenue_yesterday` from `campaign_revenue` into `new_data`.
new record in the result table should look something like:

`campaign_id | campaign_name | revenue | revenue_yesterday`
 `43243242    | testing name  | 109.02  | 159.43`

 
where what we see is actually two records from `campaign_revenue` and for each date and campaign id and name from `campaign_manager`.
 i've been trying quite few variations, but based on this [answer](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-combine-multiple-selects-in-one-query/7741)
my last attempt was this:

```
SELECT campaign_id, campaign_name
FROM campaign_manager
UNION
SELECT
    revenue
FROM campaign_revenue
WHERE data_date = '2018-02-13'
UNION
SELECT
    revenue AS revenue_yesterday
FROM campaign_revenue
WHERE data_date = '2018-02-12'
```

it clearly didn't work but i hope it help''s understand what i'm trying to achive...thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join would seem to be what you have in mind.  You may join twice to the `campaign_revenue` table, once for today's revenue, and once for yesterday's revenue.

```
SELECT
    cm.campaign_id,
    cm.campaign_name,
    cr1.data_date,
    cr1.revenue AS revenue_today,
    cr2.revenue AS revenue_yesterday
FROM campaign_manager cm
INNER JOIN campaign_revenue cr1
    ON cm.campaign_id = cr1.campaign_id
LEFT JOIN campaign_revenue cr2
    ON cm.campaign_id = cr2.campaign_id AND
       cr1.data_date = DATE_ADD(cr2.data_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
-- WHERE cr1.data_date = CURDATE()
```

This answer assumes that your dates are contiguous, that is, there are no missing dates.

Comment: You forgot to select todays date in the first join clause: `AND cr1.data_date='2018-02-13`

Comment: @micce It wasn't clear to me whether the OP wanted just today, or multiple dates.

Comment: Indeed. But the it would be best to add the data_date to the `SELECT` clause, to avoid several undistinguishable lines in the answer referring to different dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SELECT campaign_id, campaign_name FROM campaign_manager WHERE data_date IN ('2018-02-13',  '2018-01-14',  '2017-02-15') 
UNION 
SELECT title FROM data_table WHERE title IN ('2018-02-13',  '2018-01-14')
```

you need to use two queries with union keyword.

For reference : you can go to '[UNION Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)'